# Last id with subquery

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have the following pl/sql query:

```
select praca.nmpraca, pista.idpista, sentidoPista.NMSENTIDOPISTA, pista.idslt, statusSltPista.STATUS, statusSltPista.DHMMENSAGEM,
      statusSltProxy.DHMMENSAGEM, statusSltProxy.STATUS, statusAntena.DHMMENSAGEM, statusAntena.STATUS, statusMcr.DHMMENSAGEM, statusMcr.STATUS,
      chavesMcr.DHM_RECEBIDO, chavesMcr.QNT_CHAVES, statusPista.DHMMENSAGEM, statusPista.STATUS
FROM  MCR_TBPRACA praca
inner 
join  MCR_TBINATIVACAOPISTA pista
on    praca.IDTBPRACA = pista.IDPRACA
inner 
join  MCR_TBSENTIDOPISTA sentidoPista 
ON    sentidoPista.IDSENTIDOPISTA = pista.IDSENTIDOPISTA
left 
join  MCR_TBSTATUSGEACOMSLT statusSltPista
on    statusSltPista.IDPRACA = praca.IDPRACA
and   pista.IDPISTA = statusSltPista.PISTA
and   statusSltPista.IDSTATUSGEACOMSLT = (select max(s.IDSTATUSGEACOMSLT)      from MCR_TBSTATUSGEACOMSLT s where s.praca = praca.IDPRACA and s.pista = pista.IDPISTA) 
left 
join MCR_TBSTATUSLANEALIVE statusSltProxy
on   statusSltProxy.IDPISTA = pista.IDPISTA
and  statusSltProxy.IDPRACA = praca.IDPRACA
left 
join MCR_TBSTATUSANTENA statusAntena
on   statusAntena.IDPISTA = pista.IDPISTA
and  statusAntena.IDPRACA = praca.IDPRACA
left 
join MCR_TBSTATUSMCRCOMPUTADOR statusMcr
on   statusMcr.IDPISTA = pista.IDPISTA
and  statusMcr.IDPRACA = praca.IDPRACA
and  statusMcr.IDSLT = pista.IDSLT
left
join MCR_TBCHAVESMCR chavesMcr 
on   chavesMcr.IDSLT = pista.IDSLT
left 
join MCR_TBSTATUSPISTA statusPista
on   statusPista.IDPRACA = praca.IDPRACA
and  statusPista.IDPISTA = pista.IDPISTA
```

I need to get the last register of table MCR_TBSTATUSGEACOMSLT(alias statusSltPista), so I'm doing that subquery with max. However, I got this error:

> 1799. 00000 -  "a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"
>         *Cause:    (+)  () is not allowed.
>         *Action:   Either remove the (+) or make a view out of the subquery.
>                In V6 and before, the (+) was just ignored in this case.

I do understand what it's telling me, but I really don't know how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no [PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) in the question. I think you meant [SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a `JOIN` to an inline view instead:

Instead of this:

```
left join MCR_TBSTATUSGEACOMSLT statusSltPista
on statusSltPista.IDPRACA = praca.IDPRACA
and pista.IDPISTA = statusSltPista.PISTA
and statusSltPista.IDSTATUSGEACOMSLT = (select max(s.IDSTATUSGEACOMSLT) from MCR_TBSTATUSGEACOMSLT s where s.praca = praca.IDPRACA and s.pista = pista.IDPISTA)
```

You can do this:

```
left join (
    select IDPRACA, PISTA, max(IDSTATUSGEACOMSLT) as Max_IDSTATUSGEACOMSLT
    from MCR_TBSTATUSGEACOMSLT
    group by IDPRACA, PISTA
) statusSltPista
on statusSltPista.IDPRACA = praca.IDPRACA
and statusSltPista.PISTA = pista.IDPISTA
```

Just be sure to reference the "max" column correctly elsewhere in the query - using the example above, that value would be `statusSltPista.Max_IDSTATUSGEACOMSLT`